# What is the Lost+found folder in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu

My friend uses Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 in a dual boot setup. In Ubuntu there's a 12 GB partition with only one folder: `Lost+found`. I can neither open it nor access it otherwise.

What's the purpose of the `Lost+found` folder?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix

Answer (score 3):

`lost+found` is the directory in which `fsck` (filesystem check) will put files it restores from orphaned blocks. This can happen when something corrupts filesystem meta-blocks (also called i-nodes) in which the references of the blocks are stored which contain the data of a file.

Look also at http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/lostfound.html http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-229143.html

Comment: thanks so much  for your answer  i will read your link...

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel my response helped clear anything help, please could you take the time to rate it or accept it as an answer, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about Windows `chkdsk` recovered files this is basically same as `FOUND.???` folders created by `chkdsk`. So basically it contains any recovered directories, files or file fragments that are found during filesystem checking.